# Get Hazelcast EntryExpiredListener only of one node (not all replicas)

Tags: iot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have requirement where i have a continuous flow of signals and i want to be informed if there has'nt been a signal for a certain amount of time.

right now i am adding every signal to a Hazelcast map and if it has not been updated for a certain amount of time the Hazelcast EntryExpiredListener fires.

So far, so good, but the EntryExpiredListener is called for every replica, so i am notified N times.

Is there a way to be only informed in the master node or only one replica?

I am aware that i am abusing HZ a bit and i am open for other ideas too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use `IMap::addEntryListener` to register your expiry listener. Instead try to use `IMap::addLocalEntryListener` which will only be fired on the node currently owning the entry, which means you'll get one notification only.